# How to add text with checkbox repository in GridView column?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using `DevExpress` controls. I have a `GridControl` with column having `CheckboxRepository`. I want to display text with checkbox(Text+Checkbox) in column. 
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look: [How to display custom text next to a check box within the same cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2930)

> This task can be achieved by handling the following GridView/TreeList
>   events: the CustomDrawCell event (CustomDrawNodeCell for the TreeList
>   control) and the ShownEditor event. Within the CustomDraw~ event you
>   should draw a checkbox and the necessary caption:

```
private void treeList1_CustomDrawNodeCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.CustomDrawNodeCellEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Column != treeList1.Columns["Check"])
        return;

    string caption = "Node ID: " + e.Node.Id.ToString();
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo.CheckEditViewInfo viewInfo = (e.EditViewInfo as DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo.CheckEditViewInfo);

    DevExpress.Utils.Drawing.CheckObjectInfoArgs checkInfo = viewInfo.CheckInfo;

    checkInfo.Caption = caption;
    checkInfo.Graphics = e.Graphics;
    viewInfo.CheckPainter.CalcObjectBounds(checkInfo);
}
```

> The ShownEditor event handler should adjust the editor's
>   Properties.Caption property when the editor is being activated:

```
private void treeList1_ShownEditor(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList tl = sender as DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList;

    if (tl.FocusedColumn != tl.Columns["Check"])
        return;

    (tl.ActiveEditor as DevExpress.XtraEditors.CheckEdit).Properties.Caption = "Node ID: " + tl.FocusedNode.Id.ToString();
}
```